# Count occurrences of letters from a URL

Tags: java

I'm trying to count the occurrence of each letter from a URL.

I found this code, which seems to do the trick, but there are a few things I would hope to get explained.

1) I'm using a Norwegian alphabet so I need to add three more letters. I changed the array to 29, but it did not work.

2) Could you please explain to me what `%c%7d\n` means?

```
01  import java.io.FileReader;
02  import java.io.IOException;
03   
04   
05  public class FrequencyAnalysis {
06      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
07      FileReader reader = new FileReader("PlainTextDocument.txt");
08   
09      System.out.println("Letter Frequency");
10   
11      int nextChar;
12      char ch;
13   
14      // Declare 26 char counting
15      int[] count = new int[26];
16   
17      //Loop through the file char
18      while ((nextChar = reader.read()) != -1) {
19          ch = Character.toLowerCase((char) nextChar);
20   
21          if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
22          count[ch - 'a']++;
23      }
24   
25      // Print out
26      for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
27          System.out.printf("%c%7d\n", i + 'A', count[i]);
28      }
29   
30      reader.close();
31      }
32  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You havent said how you checked for the 3 additional letters. It not enough to increase the size of the `count` array. You will need to account for the new characters unicode point values here. Chances are that the values are no longer conveniently sequentially ordered. In that case, you can use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` to store the frequencies.

`%c` is the format specifier for a unicode character. `%7d` is the specifier for integer with leftmost space padding. `\n` is a newline character

Documented in the [Formatter javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 1):

An important thing here is that when you want to increment the number of occurences in your array, you are implicitly using the ASCII code of the characters :

```
//Here, ch is a char.
ch = Character.toLowerCase((char) nextChar);

  //I hate *if statements* without curly brackets but this is off-topic :)
  if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')

    /*
     * but here, ch is implicitly cast to an integer.
     * The int value of a char is its ASCII code.
     * for example, the value of 'a' is 97.
     * So if ch is 'a', (ch - 'a') = (97 - 97) = 0.
     * That's why you are incrementing count[0] in this case.
     *
     * Now, what happens if ch ='ø'? What is the ASCII code of ø?
     * Probably something quite high so that ch-'a' is probably out of bounds
     * but the size of your array is 26+3 only.
     *
     * EDIT : after a quick test, 'ø' = 248.
     *
     * This would work if norvegian characters had ASCII code between 98 and 100.
     */
     count[ch - 'a']++;
```

You should rewrite the algorithm using a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` instead.

```
//HashMap<Character, nb occurences of this character>
HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

while ((nextChar = reader.read()) != -1) {
  if(!map.containsKey(nextChar)) {
    map.put(nextChar, 0);
  }
  map.put(nextChar, map.get(nextChar)+1);
}
```